# Access 97 patch needed (?)

Tags: ms-access

I have a .mdb file here which I need to open. It's a secured database for which the Administrator's password is lost. The only known pwd is that of a normal user. The database is pretty ancient, I believe it's Access 97. It runs perfectly with the access runtime which is part of the package. That runtime is version 8.0.0.5903 (the exact version of Access 97 SR2), size 2,89 MB, Microsoft copyright notice 1991-199x (can't read the last digit), file change date 05/2002. Unfortunately, I need to open it in Access, not just the runtime.

I set up a virtual XP32 machine with Office 97, installed Access SR 2 and the latest Jet patch I found (Jet 2.5, SP 3). When I try to open the database I can log in, it briefly shows the tables list, but before I can click anything it says "The version of your database is newer than the program version. Ask your system administrator", and of course closes the DB.

When I try to open the DB with any newer version of access (e.g. Access 2000), I consistently get the error message "The current user does not have the right to convert or activate this database ..." (and I don't have the administrators pwd).

Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: Try to open while keeping SHIFT pressed. Maybe there's an autostart macro, because the wording of the error message is certainly not standard (or you did not write down the *exact* wording.)

Comment: The wording is not standard because I re-translated it from german. The Jet version I'm using is actually 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

The shift key was the solution. Thanks Tomalak!